# Method to layout graphics file and pdf file for printing

Tags: pdf, printing, cups, postscript, png

I'm working on a project to automate the creation of shipping labels, ([Avery 8127](https://www.avery.com/templates/8127)) to be exact.  I get a PNG of the USPS/UPS/FedEx shipping label, but the packing slip can vary between a PDF or a screenshot of a webpage.

My initial (quasi successful) solution was to use ImageMagick to manipulate the USPS label, convert the packing slip to a PNG and again, use ImageMagick to append them together to create a single graphics file with both images laid out correctly.

However, this isn't ideal.  I'd like the ability to generate a new document (whatever it may be, PDF, PS, image, etc.) where I layout the graphic where it needs to be and insert the text below it.  I'd like to have the ability to change the font size or add/remove text as needed.

What tools are available for this type of thing?  How can I create and lay out a new document *programmatically* based on a graphics file and a file containing text?

(Could I do this with a CUPS printer filter?)

I'm currently working on macOS, but I'm looking for something portable so I can easily move it to a FreeBSD server later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by *programmatically*, so here are some ideas.

These days, all output targets PostScript, which is itself a language, so you could write your requests in that, but it is a little difficult. (PDF is mostly convertable to PostScript). However, to overcome some limitation of a conversion tool, you can often tweak the PostScript output that it generates.

At the other extreme, there are commands like `enscript` which takes plain text and converts it to PostScript. Though intended to help print and highlight code like C and perl, you can embed commands within your plain text to change the font, and so on, or include bits of PostScript or images in EPS format.

Amongst the *markdown* languages, there is [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html) which allows you to change fonts and include images. `rst2pdf` converts it to a pdf.

The oldest typesetting language on Linux, and FreeBSD, is troff, extended under GNU to `groff`. It is purpose built to allow you to put text anywhere on a piece of paper, and can include PostScript images.  The basic commands can be a little hard to master, but there are several *macro* packages like `mm` which allow you to create a document fairly simply.

As for real programming, perl, C, java, python, probably all have some sort of library to allow you to generate pdfs to some degree.

Comment: "Programmatically" as in I have two existing files and I run a script or a program that will combine the two into a predefined layout.  I think you've put me on a good path with `enscript` and `troff`.  I didn't know they existed until now!